# Converting SQL query result to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Input data**

```
id  year    Name    provid  prov
1   1995    MAC 1995-11_CL236   reg 236
1   1995    MAC 1995-11_CL230   reg 230 (1)
1   1995    MAC 1995-11_CL229J  reg 229J
1   1995    MAC 1995-11_CL260   reg 260
```

My query looks like this

```
select  
    id, year, Name, prov, provid 
from 
    Table 
for xml path ('entry'), root('legref'), elements
```

The above Query generating different entry for each row. But I need group by id year, name and provide single entry with different prov and provid.

```
<legref>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <year>1995</year>
    <Name>MAC</Name>
    <prov>reg 229J</prov>
    <provid>NSW_REG_1995-11_CL229J</provid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <year>1995</year>
    <Name>MAC</Name>
    <prov>reg 230 (1)</prov>
    <provid>NSW_REG_1995-11_CL230</provid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <year>1995</year>
    <Name>MAC</Name>
    <prov>reg 236</prov>
    <provid>NSW_REG_1995-11_CL236</provid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <year>1995</year>
    <Name>MAC</Name>
    <prov>reg 260</prov>
    <provid>NSW_REG_1995-11_CL260</provid>
  </entry>
</legref>
```

**Output Data:**

How do I convert SQL query result to XML?

**Expected result set:**

```
<legref>
     <entry>
            <id>1<id>
            <year>1995</year>
            <Name>MAC</Name>
            <prov provID="1995-11_CL230">reg 230 (1)</prov>
            <prov provID="1995-11_CL236">reg 236</prov>
            <prov provID="1995-11_CL260">reg 260</prov>
            <prov provID="1995-11_CL229J">reg 229J</prov>
        </entry>
</legref>
```

Comment: Please don't supply sample data as an image; we can't use it. Take the time to provide it as tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements. As we can't run your code, due to a lack of consumable sample data, why didn't what you have work?

Comment: Yes - and? You have the data and you have a query - what's the question really??

Comment: Maybe you can write a SQLCLR function to convert query result to XML

Comment: My query have generate 4 entry. But I need single entry id , name, year are same but prov and provid is different. So I want this kind of format.

Comment: @NitinSawant the OP is already using a query that returns XML

Comment: @Antony update your question with the actual result and *text* instead of images. Don't force people to create tables, insert values just to see what the problem is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have added input with text format.

Comment: @Antony can you make a SQL fiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Nitin Can you please check my input again.

Comment: @Antony after your update would this help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132039/sql-server-two-level-group-by-with-xml-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4a230e0ac493142d7d2516b586c5479)**

```
SELECT ID, Year, Name, 
       (
            SELECT ProvID AS 'Prov/@ProvID',Prov
            FROM tbl t
            WHERE ID = t.ID AND Name = t.Name
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        )
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY ID, Year, Name
FOR XML PATH ('Entry'),ROOT('legref')
```

**Output**

```
<legref>
  <Entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Year>1995</Year>
    <Name>MAC</Name>
    <Prov ProvID="1995-11_CL236">Reg 236</Prov>
    <Prov ProvID="1995-11_CL230">Reg 230</Prov>
    <Prov ProvID="1995-11_CL229J">Reg 229J</Prov>
    <Prov ProvID="1995-11_CL260">Reg 260</Prov>
  </Entry>
</legref>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query,

```
SELECT id
    ,year
    ,Name
    ,prov
    ,provid
FROM TABLE
FOR XML RAW ,ELEMENTS
```

I have tried it for different table for same type of result.
Please check snap:
[image]
[image]

Comment: This isn't goinjg to generate a value like `provID="1995-11_CL260"`

Comment: The given query generated 4 entry. But I need single entry id , name, year are same but prov and provid is different.

Comment: The only thing those images show is that the result doesn't match what the OP asked for. The OP's query specifies an `entry` element inside a `legref` root, something impossible to generate with `XML RAW,ELEMENTS`